# extracting portion of filename into variable using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have two questions.  I have a folder which contains subfolders containing .txt files.  The txt files are of the format

```
{title.of.a.book}.V{4 digit year}.{4 digit issue}.txt
```

example

```
to.kill.a.mockingbird.V1960.0001.txt
```

I want to pull out three pieces of information:

1. title (with spaces instead of periods) eg: to kill a mockingbird
2. volume number eg: 1960
3. issue number eg: 0001

This is what I've written so far

```
for file in $(find /home/user/books -type f -name '*.txt')
do
    name=$(echo "$file"|sed -e 's/^\(.*\).V.*txt$/\1/')
    volume=$(echo "$file"|sed -e 's/^.*V\(\d{4}\).*$/\1/')
    issue=$(echo "$file"|sed -e 's/^.*\(\d{4}\).txt$/\1/')
    echo "$name" "$volume" "$issue"
done
```

1. How to pull out the 3 pieces of info to separate variables
2. How to replace the `.` with spaces

I can't decide whether to rename the file first (rename `s/./ /g`) - or to rename the `$name` afterwards.

The name variable prints correctly, but the volume and issue number variables just print the filename out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15329515/15168) by [speakr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337398/speakr) is probably best, but I am still old-school and like `sed`.

You can supply multiple commands to `sed` in a single `-e` argument, separated by semicolons, or in multiple `-e` arguments; I more usually use the latter.  I'd also clean up the name from `find` to remove the leading path.  Then you need to decide whether you're using extended regular expressions of not, and you need to be consistent in what you use.

Using GNU `sed` 4.4.2 (©2012), I can't get the `\d` notation to recognize digits; there's probably something silly here.

Without extended regular expressions (will work with non-GNU versions of `sed`):

```
for file in $(find /home/user/books -type f -name '*.txt')
do
    base=$(basename $file .txt)
    name=$(  echo "$base" | sed -e 's/^\(.*\).V.*$/\1/' -e 's/\./ /g') # replace dots
    volume=$(echo "$base" | sed -e 's/^.*V\([0-9]\{4\}\).*$/\1/')
    issue=$( echo "$base" | sed -e 's/^.*\([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\1/')
    echo "$name" "$volume" "$issue"
done
```

Output for the example book:

```
to kill a mockingbird 1960 0001
```

Using GNU `sed`'s 'extended regular expression' mode (`-r`):

```
for file in $(find /home/user/books -type f -name '*.txt')
do
    base=$(basename $file .txt)
    name=$(  echo "$base" | sed -r -e 's/^(.*).V.*$/\1/' -e 's/\./ /g') # replace dots
    volume=$(echo "$base" | sed -r -e 's/^.*V([0-9]{4}).*$/\1/')
    issue=$( echo "$base" | sed -r -e 's/^.*([0-9]{4})$/\1/')
    echo "$name" "$volume" "$issue"
done
```

Using the `\d` notation (incorrect output):

```
for file in $(find /home/user/books -type f -name '*.txt')
do
    base=$(basename $file .txt)
    name=$(  echo "$base" | sed -r -e 's/^(.*).V.*$/\1/' -e 's/\./ /g') # replace dots
    volume=$(echo "$base" | sed -r -e 's/^.*V(\d{4}).*$/\1/')
    issue=$( echo "$base" | sed -r -e 's/^.*(\d{4})$/\1/')
    echo "$name" "$volume" "$issue"
done
```

Output:

```
to kill a mockingbird to.kill.a.mockingbird.V1960.0001 to.kill.a.mockingbird.V1960.0001
```

Comment: This also works - thank you for all the help! Would also vote up for this but I don't have enough reputation!!

Answer (score 3):

No need to use sed, bash can handle it with param expansions.

Assuming that all your text files use the mentioned format:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find /home/user/books -type f -name '*.txt'); do
    pre=${file%%.txt}
    pre=${pre//./ }
    name=${pre%% V*}
    volume=${pre##* V}
    volume=${volume%% *}
    issue=${pre##* }
    echo "Name: '$name' Volume: '$volume' Issue: '$issue'"
done
```

Comment: This works, thank you! - I wanted to vote up but it won't let me!!